# General recommendations to increase the number of questions of a site

Tags: support, questions, area-51, statistics

Our site is [Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/).

I have asked this too [at our meta](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1832/what-can-we-do-to-increase-the-number-of-questions-on-the-site), but maybe you can give us some 
recommendations applicable to other Stack Exchange sites and so a helpfull question here on main meta.

The question is [Area51 is showing this stat](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36296/earth-science):

[image]

What can we do to increase the number of questions on a Stack Exchange site?

Comment: Publicise it: tell all your friends about it, blog about it, mention it at conferences.

Comment: Writing encouraged their users with [a little contest](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1810/23159), which had an immediate effect - which in turn dropped as soon as the contest was over. Still, regularly doing contests / tag challenges / ... can be effective.

Comment: Maybe just make it a personal project to ask at least one at least decent question a day. Read something, google for 10 minutes and then ask away. That would increase this metric already by a stunning 40%. How do Taifuns differ from Hurricans? Why is there so much water on Earth? Where did it come from? When will there be no more snow on Earth?  What is the probability for a major Earth quake in [insert your location]? What is the longest river of the world? How much energy could possibly get generated from Wind? ... other possible stuff

Comment: I offer the bounty to PolyGeo, but the post is being watched at Earth Science and any new advice is welcome.

Comment: I just took a peek and it looks like Earth Sciences already looks great.  You know what they say: be careful what you wish for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you just need to stick to the basics:

- encourage people to ask questions, and ask them yourself
- encourage people to answer questions, and answer them yourself
- encourage people to vote, and vote yourself
- encourage improvement of your existing content, and comment and curate yourself

Advertise your site when you can. We at the [Genealogy & Family History](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com) have a lower than we would like questions per day so we empathize with you.

Answer (score 3):

#### *Pay it forward...*

Just throwing this out there (I don't know if it's really a good idea).

- On meta.SE, every month we select a different small site (the "target" site) to help out.  During that month, we become active at the target site: we make noise and get the site noticed.  We cast lots of votes, ask lots of questions, make lots of edits.  Whatever is needed, and whatever we can reasonably do.
- The next month, which site do we help out?  From the sites that have yet to receive help, we select the one that has been the most active in helping out.

I feel many veteran Stack Exchangers could ask a reasonable question at a site like Earth Sciences, something that's taught in school.  (E.g., just read a random Wikipedia page and ask about whatever claim has "[citation needed]" next to it.)  It may not be so easy at more specific sites.